# How to take articles from LexisNexis with script

Tags: api, scripting

I'm working on a research project with a professor at my university. Right now we're collecting data and the method he has me using is painfully tedious. I have a specific search criteria that I search for in LexisNexis. I repeatedly have to change the year and change one parameter of the search. I'll have to do this a couple thousand times to get all the data collected.

I want to write a script that will help speed up this progress, but I'm having trouble interpreting the LexisNexis API. Here's a link to [the API](http://www.amdev.net/docs/LexisNexis_Academic_URL_API_Specification_ver2010.pdf). I'm hoping to write a script that runs my search and automatically augments the year and parameter.

I can write the script myself if I understand how to use the API.

Answer (score 2):

From the linked document:

> Without limitation, you acknowledge that LexisNexis prohibits the use
>   of scripts  and other automated means of conducting multiple searches
>   on LexisNexis Academic

I was wondering the same thing, but I don't think we are allowed to script our searches.

Comment: Why would they create an API then?